# Pandas Dataframe Mask based on index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.date_range('2013-1-1',periods=10,freq='15Min')
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], columns=['value'], index=index)
```

How can I generate a mask based on the index value? I know I can do something like:

```
data['value'] > 3
Out[40]: 
2013-01-01 00:00:00    False
2013-01-01 00:15:00    False
2013-01-01 00:30:00    False
2013-01-01 00:45:00     True
2013-01-01 01:00:00     True
2013-01-01 01:15:00     True
2013-01-01 01:30:00     True
2013-01-01 01:45:00     True
2013-01-01 02:00:00     True
2013-01-01 02:15:00    False
Freq: 15T, Name: value, dtype: bool
```

I want to generate a mask to only consider some rows where the index is in a certain range. I was thinking of doing something like `data['index'].time() > datetime.time(1,15)` to generate a mask. Except of course `data['index']` fails because index is not the name of a column. How can you reference the index value for a row in a mask?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can mask using `indexer_between_time`:

```
In [11]: data.index.indexer_between_time(start='01:15', end='02:00')
Out[11]: array([5, 6, 7, 8])

In [12]: data.iloc[data.index.indexer_between_time(start='1:15', end='02:00')]
Out[12]:
                     value
2013-01-01 01:15:00      6
2013-01-01 01:30:00      7
2013-01-01 01:45:00      8
2013-01-01 02:00:00      9
```

*As you can see, you access the index by the attribute `.index`.*

Note: `indexer_between_time` by default both `include_start` and `include_end` are True, it also offers a `tz` argument to compare the time to a different timezone.

Comment: on dft with 2015-08-11 data: dft['2015-08-11 12:00:00':'2015-08-11 12:30:00'] takes 927 microseconds, whereas dft.ix[dft.index.indexer_between_time('12:00', '12:30') takes 402 and dft.iloc[dft.index.indexer_between_time('12:00', '12:30') 421 microseconds. So indexer_between_time seems 2x faster... (nota: on last pandas docs, iloc is said deprecated, use .ix instead)

Comment: @comte "iloc is said deprecated, use .ix instead" are you sure about that, this seems wrong. You should *prefer* to use iloc (as it's more descriptive... and faster). Can't find mention of this deprecation online.

Comment: @Andy, you're correct, i made a mistake on my notes, it's .irow() and .icol() that are deprecated since 0.11 (ref in docs)[http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html]

Answer (score 7):

'start' and 'stop' keywords are deprecated.With pandas >17.1; I had to use the following syntax instead:

```
data.iloc[data.index.indexer_between_time('1:15', '02:00')]
Out[90]: 
                     value
2013-01-01 01:15:00      6
2013-01-01 01:30:00      7
2013-01-01 01:45:00      8
2013-01-01 02:00:00      9
```