# Python: create a new dataframe column and write the index correspondig to datetime intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe :

```
 date_time             value     member
2013-10-09 09:00:00  664639  Jerome
2013-10-09 09:05:00  197290  Hence
2013-10-09 09:10:00  470186  Ann
2013-10-09 09:15:00  181314  Mikka
2013-10-09 09:20:00  969427  Cristy
2013-10-09 09:25:00  261473  James
2013-10-09 09:30:00  003698  Oliver
```

and the second dataframe where I have the bounds like :

```
   date_start            date_end
2013-10-09 09:19:00         2013-10-09 09:25:00
2013-10-09 09:25:00         2013-10-09 09:40:00
```

so I need to create a new column where I will write the index of each interval between two datetime points:

smth like:

```
date_time             value     member    session
2013-10-09 09:00:00  664639  Jerome        1
2013-10-09 09:05:00  197290  Hence         1
2013-10-09 09:10:00  470186  Ann            1
2013-10-09 09:15:00  181314  Mikka          2
2013-10-09 09:20:00  969427  Cristy         2
2013-10-09 09:25:00  261473  James          2
2013-10-09 09:30:00  003698  Oliver         2
```

the following code creates the column `'session'`, but doesn't write the index of session (i.e. index of row in `bounds` dataframe) in `'session'` column, so don't separate the initial dataframe on intervals:

```
def create_interval():
    df['session']=''
    for index, row in bounds.iterrows():
        s = row['date_start']
        e = row['date_end']
        mask=(df['date'] > s) & (df['date'] < e)
        df.loc[mask]['session']='[index]'

    return df
```

**UPDATE**

problem that code `bounds['date_start'].searchsorted(df['date_time'])` doesn't give the result I want to obtain, i.e. one index value for every interval: `df['Session']` = 1 for first interval, =2 for second and so on. Columns `Session` is aimed to separate different intervals that lye in between `date_start` and `date_end` of `bounds`
I suppose that if df['date_time'] not the same that bounds['start_date'] it already increments index for `session`, that not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: I don't understand why the session value is 1 for only rows up to time `09:15:00` when the  `date_start` in `bounds` begins at `09:19:00`?

Comment: @EdChum, sorry, I just gave the example of structure of dataframe I have, not the exact value! if you need the exact value to come up with answer, don't hesitate to ask me for that!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17559885/2325172) question and answers could probably help you.

Comment: Please post the incorrect output and the desired output, English has subtlety in meanings that code does not

Comment: @EdChum I posted the incorrect output and the desired output, please let me know if you need smth else

Comment: Does my first solution work though? ` df['date_time'].apply(lambda x: np.searchsorted(bounds['date_start'], x)[0])`?

Comment: @EdChum, it has the same incorrect output that I posted above

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work for you, it works fine for me

Comment: @EdChurn so you are sure ,for each interval it assigns a  unique index? 1 for fist interval, 2 for second, 3 for third and so on (interval is the rows between date_start and date_end of  ```bounds```)?

Comment: like this: `In [306]:

df
df['Session'] = bounds['date_start'].searchsorted(df['date_time'])
df
Out[306]:
            date_time  Session
0 2015-07-30 10:32:54        0
1 2015-07-30 10:32:54        0
2 2015-07-30 10:36:39        1
3 2015-07-30 10:36:39        1
4 2015-07-30 10:36:39        1
5 2015-07-30 10:36:39        1
6 2015-07-30 10:37:00        1
7 2015-07-30 10:37:00        1
8 2015-07-30 10:37:00        1
9 2015-07-30 10:37:00        1` same as your desired output

Comment: @EdChum, I understood finally what happens! you are right, code works, but actually this method doesn't include the start_date itself into interval, so it disturbed me! do you know how I can include the start_date in each interval?

Comment: that's the default behaviour of searchsorted it it matches then it the index is the position before the current index value if you want it to fall into the next bin value then you'd need to widen the start interval perhaps so subtract 1 second from it or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the actual index location (zero-based), you can call `apply` on your 'date_time' column and call `np.searchsorted` to find the index location of where in `bounds` df it falls in:

```
In [266]:
df['Session'] = df['date_time'].apply(lambda x: np.searchsorted(bounds['date_start'], x)[0])
df

Out[266]:
            date_time   value  member  Session
0 2013-10-09 09:00:00  664639  Jerome        0
1 2013-10-09 09:05:00  197290   Hence        0
2 2013-10-09 09:10:00  470186     Ann        0
3 2013-10-09 09:15:00  181314   Mikka        0
4 2013-10-09 09:20:00  969427  Cristy        1
5 2013-10-09 09:25:00  261473   James        1
6 2013-10-09 09:30:00    3698  Oliver        2
```

**EDIT**

@Jeff has pointed out that `apply` is unnecessary here and of course he's right, this will be much faster:

```
In [293]:
df['session'] = bounds['date_start'].searchsorted(df['date_time']) 
df

Out[293]:
            date_time   value  member  session
0 2013-10-09 09:00:00  664639  Jerome        0
1 2013-10-09 09:05:00  197290   Hence        0
2 2013-10-09 09:10:00  470186     Ann        0
3 2013-10-09 09:15:00  181314   Mikka        0
4 2013-10-09 09:20:00  969427  Cristy        1
5 2013-10-09 09:25:00  261473   James        1
6 2013-10-09 09:30:00    3698  Oliver        2
```

Comment: No need to use apply here: ```In [40]: bounds['date_start'].searchsorted(df['date_time'])
Out[40]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2])```

Comment: Further, technically this should be bounds between the start/end times (e.g. searchsorted would return -1 if its out of bounds), but that's a detail that the OP didn't present data for.

Comment: @Jeff yes that's true the problem domain has not been fully described but the OP seems happy with the behaviour here, `-1` to mark OOB is not a necessarily bad thing though

Comment: it doesn't work for me when I verified, actually I need have an index incremented +1 for every session, but if, for example, in ```bounds``` dataframe I have the following two first date_start:  2015-07-30 10:32:54.000 ,   2015-07-30 11:58:57.000  , after applying your code , I have a incremented index in ```Session``` already for 2015-07-30 10:36:39.000 in  ```df ```   dataframe , that comes next to 2015-07-30 10:32:54.000 , i.e. it means that it should be the second interval despite the fact it stay int the same interval according the ```bounds``` dataframe

Comment: So why not just add `1`? `df['session'] = bounds['date_start'].searchsorted(df['date_time']) + 1`?

Comment: Also edit into your question what your updated requirements are with an explanation, formatting is lost in comments

Comment: it's not the point, adding 1 just replaces 0 with 1, 1 with 2, but my problem that ```bounds['date_start'].searchsorted(df['date_time'])``` doesn't give the result I want to obtain, i.e. : Session = 1 for first interval, =2 for second and so on. Columns ```Session``` is aimed to separate different inervales that lye in between date_start and date_end of ```bounds```

Comment: Again I ask you, edit your question, also show why my code snippet doesn't work

Comment: @EdChum, sorry, haven't seen that comment, done updated!